# PM2 serve SPA build folder. It works but has tons of errors like "Error while serving ... ENOENT: no such file or directory..."

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, pm2, serve

The problem is that the logs are flooded, but it works fine.

The build folder contains the build from React using CRA (Create React App).
So from the [PM2 Docs](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/expose/) I have this:

**ecosystem.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "projectName",
    script: "serve",
    watch: true,
    env: {
        NODE_ENV: "production",
        PM2_SERVE_PATH: './build',
        PM2_SERVE_PORT: 5001,
        PM2_SERVE_SPA: 'true',
        PM2_SERVE_HOMEPAGE: './index.html'
    },
}
```

I'm using [PM2 serve command](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/expose/).

**Command to start PM2 process:**
`pm2 start`

**Errors**
*Only happens when I enter for the first time or when I reload.*
`Error while serving /.../projectName/build/routeX with content-type text/plain : ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/.../projectName/build/routeX'`

Comment: Does it happen if you run your project without pm2 and what exactly is hiding behind that 'serve' script?

Comment: It's a frontend project, built on React, I serve static files.

If I run the project with https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve it works fine. 

But if I use pm2 serve command https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/expose/ errors happens, but It works fine too.

The problem is that these errors are taking up space on the disk because they happen each time someone enters the web or uses F5 on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed in pm2 v5.2.0

https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/pull/5272

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to find the nature of those requests leading to an error. If they are originated from your app, then you have either to put away what causes that request or let something to be in that place inside of your build folder (depends on request's reason). If they are originated not from your app, then you should figure out where they come from. "Network" Tab of DevTools should help you in both cases

Comment: Today I cleaned up some nginx files I was no longer using and the errors are gone. It seems that nginx was listening two servers at the same time and that was causing some confusion. Thanks anyways!